# React js react-dropzone upload file calculate sha256

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, sha256, react-dropzone

I'm using `react-dropzone`, I would need a way to be able to calculate the `sha256` of the file when the file is selected then inside the `onDrop()` function, to use it as a checksum for the checks I'm doing.

I thought of using `CryptoJS`, but it doesn't return to me what I hope it should return to me, that is, a 64-character code.

```
function Dropzone(props) {
    const { acceptedFiles, getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
        onDrop: props.onDrop
    });
    const file = acceptedFiles[0];
    return (
        <div>
            <Typography>File Name</Typography>
            {file ? (
                <p>
                    {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
                </p>
            ) : (
                <p />
            )}
            <div {...getRootProps({ className: 'drop-zone' })}>
                <input {...getInputProps()} multiple={false} />
                <p>Drag 'n' drop files here, or click to select files</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

const onDrop = files => {
        console.log(files);
    };

<Dropzone onDrop={onDrop} multiple={false} />
```

Comment: have you tried js-sha256? It supports ByteArray as input. https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha256

Comment: I'm seeing it right now, but I'm not understanding how to convert the File to Hash, if I do something like this it gives me error `sha256 (files [0])` Uncaught (in promise) Error: input is invalid type
    at Sha256.push ../ node_modules / js-sha256 / src / sha256.js.Sha256.update

Comment: If you look at the usage, there's an example with the FileReader API which can help you with `readAsArrayBuffer`, https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone#usage